# Rename filename inside the crontab file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

i have below file is my crontab,

```
00 * * * * /home/@@@@/ulimit_nofile_status_20480.sh >> /export/####/$$$$$/ulimit_nofile_status.txt

00 * * * * /home/@@@@/ulimit_nproc_status_20480.sh >> /export/####/%%%%/ulimit_nproc_status.txt
```

i want to change the file name (ulimit_nofile_status_20480.sh and ulimit_nproc_status_20480.sh) to (ulimit_nofile_status_40960.sh and ulimit_nproc_status_40960.sh) these are file names.

I want to rename 20480 to 40960

Had tried below commands but did not work for me.

```
crontab -l | sed 's#/_20480\.#/40960.#' | crontab -

crontab -l | sed 's/\<_20480\>/40960/' | crontab -
```

Comment: They won't work filename doesn't contain `/` or `<` or `>` - what do you expect these to do?

Comment: Although you could do it over a script, I still strongly recommend to use `crontab -e` and use the search replace function in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I would personly just use `crontab -e` to edit, but if you want to do it using sed, this line seems to do it:

```
crontab -l | sed 's/20480/40960/' | crontab -
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
crontab -l | sed 's/_20480\./_40960./'
```

If that works, then (and *only* then), use this to actually make the change:

```
crontab -l | sed 's/_20480\./_40960./' | crontab -
```

The reason your first attempt didn't work is that you had "`/_20480\.`" as the pattern, and the slash kept it from matching. It looks like you mixed using "/" and "#" as pattern delimiters; you can use either one, but not both at once. (I used "/" above.)

The reason your second attempt didn't work is that you tried to use `\<` and `\>` in the pattern. Some variants of regular expression syntax use these as word-boundary delimiters, but the variant that `sed` uses ([POSIX "basic" regex syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards)) doesn't -- they're just treated as the literal characters "<" and ">", and since those don't occur in the filename, it didn't match.